# HTML : Unable to view the base64 image in html report

Tags: java, html, image, base64, selenium-extent-report

In selenium I am auto mailing the extent reports through javamail API. I am using base 64 encoder to generate screenshots and attach to the report. The issue is the screenshot is visible as thumbnail but when i zoom it, it displays the encoded image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33CG6.png)

```
String scnShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
String s="data:image/png;base64,"+scnShot;
test.log(LogStatus.INFO,test.addScreenCapture(s));
```

[image]

Comment: Extent version?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. My version is 3.1.2. Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ExtentTest then this function would defienietly works, You can add screenshot with description...

```
public void LOGWithScreenshot(ExtentTest logger, String status, String TestDescription) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    String Base64StringofScreenshot="";
    File src = ((TakesScreenshot) driverThread).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    byte[] fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(src);
    Base64StringofScreenshot = "data:image/png;base64,"+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("pass"))
        logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, TestDescription+"\n"+logger.addBase64ScreenShot(Base64StringofScreenshot));
    else
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, TestDescription+"\n"+logger.addBase64ScreenShot(Base64StringofScreenshot));
}
```

Comment: Thank you solved  the problem which  I had in attaching extent report in Extent reports.

Answer (score 0):

From extent_reports GIT - [you can check here](https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/issues/715)

*Base64 images are currently not supported in this version due to issues they have caused on the previous versions and ....*

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in selenium C#, you can modify to use this in Java:

You just need to convert the image to Base64 image and use Media entity builder.

```
Screenshot file = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
string image = file.AsBase64EncodedString;

exTest.Pass(msg, MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(image).Build());
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("PASS >>>>  " + msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is coming because of below code. you are using `test.addScreencapture` which expects screencapture file  path as parameter and you are passing base64 string.

```
test.log(LogStatus.INFO,test.addScreenCapture(s));
```

To pass base64string in the extent log just use below code

```
test.info("your message "+ s)
```

where s is your base64 string