# Screenshot is not attached to the extend report when ran in Jenkins only

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

When using remote-webdriver instance of BrowserStack,  only when ran in Jenkins, the failed screenshot is not attached to the report. please help. folder structure is ExtentReport\Screenshots

[image: screenshot is missing]

I tried [Extent Report: Not able to see the screenshots on other machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062006/extent-report-not-able-to-see-the-screenshots-on-other-machine)
this but it's not resolve the issue.

```
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        testMap.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
        //add screenshot for failed test.
        WebDriver driver= WebDriverFactory.getDriver();
        //experimental to get screenshot
        driver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
        String dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date());
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/ExtentReport/" + "/Screenshots/" + result.getMethod().getMethodName() + dateName + ".png";
        File finalDestination = new File(destination);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(source, finalDestination);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        testMap.get().addScreenCaptureFromPath(destination,result.getMethod().getMethodName());

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer of ravi creed,

[HTML : Unable to view the base64 image in html report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583415/html-unable-to-view-the-base64-image-in-html-report)

```
String base64Screenshot ="data:image/png;base64," + ((TakesScreenshot) Objects.requireNonNull(driver)).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
        testMap.get().addScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64Screenshot).getModel().getMedia().get(0);
```

I managed to solve this using above code.Once click on base64 img, it opens the actual screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Different operating systems use different characters as file and path separators. When our application has to run on multiple platforms, we need to handle these correctly.
To handle this issue Java provide `File.separator`.
So, instead of

```
String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/ExtentReport/" + "/Screenshots/" + result.getMethod().getMethodName() + dateName + ".png";
```

Try this:

```
String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "ExtentReport" +  File.separator +"Screenshots" + File.separator + result.getMethod().getMethodName() + dateName + ".png";
```

To use it you will have to add this import

```
import java.io.File;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is a good way to keep the code robust, so I upvoted it . Seems it's an issue with Extent report itself. https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/issues/1118 Thanks a lot again.

Comment: I use Extent report too. You have to pass it an absolute path. And path should be built according to the OS you are working on.

Comment: I use htmlSparkReporter, may I know what  type of extent report that you are using ?

Comment: My listener implements ITestListener